# What squeezes out juice better, auger or press?

Tags: cookware, juice, juicing, aluminum-cookware

I'm thinking to buy manual juicer. I considering two options: plastic auger one or thick aluminium press.

Like this:

[image]

And this:
[image]

Comment: This depends on what you want to juice.  Clearly your pictures illustrate different juicing processes, but I always worry about most kitchen plastics when any significant force is necessary, because it flexes much more than metal.

Comment: For the specific green item, I suggest you consult the amazon reviews - there's an image of the auger self-destructing after a fairly small amount of use. I get fairly good results with the Kitchen-aid attachment (plastic auger, metal screen) though it's annoying to clean up. I can't tell where the screen mechanism is in this one or what it looks like, but the reviews are fairly negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the top apparatus gets my vote:
takes care of breaking up the juice vesicles and the pressure of the top plunger helps squeeze it out.

I find so many unpopped juice vesicles in my Mexican citrus press (bottom picture). Too much pressure and I get unwanted bitterness from oils of peel

Comment: I've been known to use a Vittoreo strainer https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vittorio+strainer&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images and the like. Trouble is, if ut's not made of high quality materials it'll break when the back pressure on the auger gets too high. I've lost a couple that way, and there's really no way to judge the strength of plastic parts from an online picture. Augers are nice, but I *prefer* metal, and even then you can wreck them with too strong an arm.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stanger I already have some model (not those at the picture) of plastic auger - use it sometime and it's fine, my just stucks when pressure is too high and I should rotate it back and then it's fine, thank for info about Vittoreo thought.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer a wooden reamer.

[image: wooden reamer]

My preference is based on durability and ease of general long term maintenance. Also because it just kinda looks cool.

From a standpoint of maintenance and long-term durability I would suggest the metallic press will be the better of the choices you provided. I am basing this on metal vs. plastic and the fact that the press has fewer mechanical parts (fewer parts means fewer breaking points).

The top auger will likely be more efficient at extracting juice. I am basing this on the fact that the torque involved should produce more mechanical force (unless very poorly designed, which may be the case based on the comment regarding product reviews).

Comment: thanks, it seems you're right about mechanical force, but about durability: a lot of metal small presses being broken after one or several use, I have those plastic auger already (not those at the picture thought) and it's hugely more reliable than small metal garlic presses.

Comment: @RS My process for evaluating based on a glance of a photo was slightly flawed which is why I explained the thought process. Metal doesnt always outlive plastic. Shoddy craftsmanship leads to more broken kitchen gear for me than anything .

Answer (score 0):

Personally i've found that using the metal press is always better as far as fruits and veggies go.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! In what way did you find it was better? Do you have examples of other types doing something wrong? Please consider expanding this answer. Take a look at the [help] page. Specifically the "how to write a good answer" link.

Comment: Yeah, would nice to hear more. But, thanks anyway.